# how to hold all artisan command laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How to disable all artisan command?

i try with create parent class and extend that class to my artisan commands.

Parent

```
namespace App\Extenders;

use Illuminate\Console\Command AS BaseCommand;

class Command extends BaseCommand {
  public function __construct()
  {
     parent::__construct();
     dump('command disabled');
     exit;
  }
}
```

My artisan command:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Extenders\Command;

class HoldAllArtisanCommand extends Command
{
  protected $signature = 'command';
  protected $description = 'Command description';

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function handle()
  {
    //
  }
}
```

With this code the command not running but all command that not extend my custom parent command is not running as well

Comment: Are you trying to disable all commands from running when one is? Or are you trying to stop that same command from running once running? Or just top them all for some random reason?

Comment: @Juakali92 not all, only command that extends BaseCommand

Comment: i'm really confused on the actual use case for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to disable your commands entirely but here is how I would do it:

First I would create an environment variable called `COMMANDS_DISABLED` and then create a config for it inside `config/app.php` and call it `commands_disabled`. OR just create a setting on the database so that I you enable and disable commands as you like.

You can create a `BaseCommand` class that extends the `Illuminate\Console\Command` like so:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class BaseCommand extends Command
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (config('app.commands_disabled')) {
            dump('command disabled');
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Then for all your custom commands inside `app/Console/Commands` you have to extend from this `BaseCommand` like so:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class TestCommand extends BaseCommand
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'testing';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

now when you run `php artisan testing` it will show the message `command disabled`.
And if you want to enable your custom commands again you can remove the constructor code from the `BaseCommand` class.

Comment: With your code, all command that not extend BaseCommand class not running as well.
I only need command that extend the BaseCommand to stop from running